# Graph Keeps Growing, Even After Clearing It

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to graph two different graphs using this Python program:

```
K_5=nx.complete_graph(10)
print(K_5.number_of_nodes(), K_5.number_of_edges())
nx.draw(K_5)
plt.savefig('test1.png')
K_5.clear()
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(8)
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig('test2.png')
print(G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges())
```

Which results in the following graphs:

[[image: This graph is correct]]
[[image: This one is not. The outlying point should be the only element present in the graph]]

I have done quite a bit of digging through Stackoverflow and the matplotlib documentation, but have been unable to find anything useful. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you use `Graph.clear()`, all the nodes and edges already removed from your graph. You can check it by printing `K_5.number_of_nodes()` after you call `Graph.clear()`. However, after you plot the first figure, you don't clear it, hence, it plots on top of the first figure.

So you need to clear the matplotlib's current figure. You can use [`plt.clf()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

K_5=nx.complete_graph(10)
print(K_5.number_of_nodes(), K_5.number_of_edges())
nx.draw(K_5)
plt.savefig('test1.png')
K_5.clear()

plt.clf() # new line, to clear the old drawings

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(8)
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig('test2.png')
print(G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges())
```

**test1.png:**

[image]

**test2.png:**

[image]